# Is there a sigkill for threads?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I imagine some threads might be unwilling to die.

```
t = Thread.new { begin
                    puts 'do'
                    sleep 10
                    puts 'done'
                 ensure
                    loop { puts "really don't wanna die" }
                 end
               }
```

^Imagine what happens if you try to `Thread#kill` this pesky bastard.

Answer (score 0):

```
t.exit
t.alive? => false
```

if you're using traps, you should read about `trap("EXIT")`

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking on how to kill a process, you can just do

```
Process.kill("KILL", pid)
```

Once it gets kill -9, the kernel then kill the process itself. killing thread with it.
also, you can trap this signal and kill it gracefully

```
Signal.trap("KILL")  { puts "Child died" }
```

Does that answer your question?

Comment: "also, you can trap this signal and kill it gracefully"--you can't. SIGKILL is one of those untrappable signals.

Comment: Try it out. The second snippet will give you an Errno::EINVAL exception.

Comment: I'm asking if there's a way to sigkill a thread without sigkilling the whole process. It wouldn't seem like unreasonable design, though, if there wasn't one -- If my children threads misbehave, I deserve to be SIGKILLed with them.